# Django file upload with "application/octet-stream" content-type

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have a 3rd side service which making a POST request with file to my Django application.To success upload to Django application request must have 'multipart/form-data' content type but content type is 'octet-stream' in my case and Request.FILES is always empty. How can i receive file with 'octet-stream' content type in django?

```py
request.content_type # is octet-stream 
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES)
file = form.cleaned_data[file_name]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody stuck too I found a some solution. You can just read data as bytes and then save it to file

```
with open(file_name, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(request.read())
```